# Calling a smart contract function inside another in web3

Tags: web3js, metamask

Here is  my code Sample in js script connected to ContractInstance through web3:

```
ContractInstance.Fire(function(error,res){
   if(!error){ContractInstance.dead.call(function(err, result){
              console.log(result);});}
             });

ContractInstance.dead.call(function(err, result){
                  console.log(result) });
```

- So when I call **fire function** of contract then my dead variable
  changes to true (I confirm it in remix )
- And then I call **dead variable** inside Fire function.
- Somehow it prints **false** in the console, but later when I call it
  outside the function it prints **true**.

I don't know why this is happening maybe because

- when I call fire function it stops for a while because metamask asks
  for confirmation .
- or it might be due to the fact that it does not update in the
  contract so quickly.

Can somebody help me how should I call dead variable just after the the fire function is called ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first callback from `.Fire` returns a transaction receipt. This is very minimal information that indicates that your node is aware of the transaction. Think "ack."

The next step is to wait for the transaction to be mined. Basically, wait for a block to arrive that includes the TxHash you got from the first callback.

The effect of the transaction is not apparent until after it's mined. That's why you're getting results on the console (immediately) that differ from what you see (later) when you check it yourself.

Have a look at this handy tool: https://gist.github.com/xavierlepretre/88682e871f4ad07be4534ae560692ee6

Hope it helps.

Comment: Oh I see.. thank you for that knowledge. So for the solution sake I shall make an event named dead in my contract, I think that will do?